# Keep user logged in to ASP.NET 5 website for long time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want users who select the "remember me" option to stay logged in to my website for a long time (e.g. 3 months, or until they clear cookies). Currently I have to log in again every 20 mins or so.

I'm using ASP.NET 5 / vnext / mvc 6 (beta 7). My website is based on the code visual studio makes as a template project. I know other questions ask a similar thing, but I don't see how it applies in the new ASP.NET.

I have this code in my Startup.ConfigureServices method, but it doesn't seem to have an effect:

```
    services.ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie(options =>
    {              
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOff");
    });
```

thanks

**EDIT**

Using fiddler, the response from logging in contains this cookie data:

> Response sent 642 bytes of Cookie data:   Set-Cookie:
>   .AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application=CfDJ8P8cKnxL87ZMjh0duvm7eKbBbA_vf1ECr95KgPd4MNsKBj0_SljMLWLPNzNFIr4PQTG1ZjVyQ7cfFMEehcI5JZrOlVVHfZ_SD29jN1vdhsdUMPTysvhvo6RlnDHq5YwFdnTNqw-_ia4cGWk8Iw05PJHsQ0mws_e0DzWpX088kysJuU0LcNoyPA22nyMoGrK1RP1Bax_XwixdO6jLQx164lqRqVYi6ys3VVPJP0aLOg3w4CovxcAemgMQEhAcNUdP6Q0rnBmfBn7FZR_kNEgXoiMkNNgBDwUuVyiweU3fw5rzE-mmBPo2IYBJWRoaSzNLcUV5gSTpDT2n8IMh4nPlTzGrFIUgCpHDhpmXJJ3EneC5i-eVaLGeQG1FAIBZZ-oNlolwdkXi63bXpHuRME9cnYLTm3cDpfooXKq0_Rn7ls4lN-wCF5kGvz6ALruUaPWNERvcKlccix7o3B_-rj1q5yhn1bKO2vumArRaq-QpHb2djaN84IdFBOw1CSJLpeQKeP3qrdJD8-GYl6chvbJ4FbA;
>   expires=Mon, 04 Jan 2016 10:40:35 GMT; path=/; httponly

You can see at the end the expire time is in 90 days, which is correct, yet it will still log me out in 20 mins or so.

Comment: Have you ever used [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?  This will tell you the response from your page and how the cookies have been returned to the client and also what you're sending to the application.  This might help you diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: How are you actually saving the cookie to the client?

Comment: Phil, I haven't used fiddler, I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: Russ, I'm using the SignInManager class, PasswordSignInAsync(...), I'm not sure how this works under the hood, it has a parameter for "isPersistent", which gets set to true, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Phil I've editted the question with the cookie data. thanks

Comment: "20 mins or so" sounds suspiciously like the default timeout on an ASP.NET session. When the browser sends the cookie to your site, the identity token might still be valid independently of whether or not the user session is still active - if the session has expired, then the user is going to need to re-authenticate. If this is what is happening, then the usual thing to do would be to implement rolling sessions - i.e. extend the session lifetime each time the user presents you with a valid cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You have key storage problem? Check Your logs if cookie encryption keys are properly stored. If app cannot persist keys they will be regenerated after restart, so all logins will be invalidated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-2.1

To enable `user profile` on IIS check app pool settings. If You host on windows 7 there is mess in default settings for app pools.

Answer (score -3):

You can add [cookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx) to the Cookies collection in a number of ways. The following example shows two methods to write cookies:

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```